# How CQRS with EventSourcing optimizes read/write

Tags: scaling, cqrs, event-sourcing

From what I understand CQRS & ES are there to help us optimize read and writes operations independently. When using separated databases for reading/write we can set up appropriate indexes in reading DB so read can be efficient and also we can quickly save data to event stores with the cost of eventual consistency.

Here's my problem: if data in both databases need to be synchronized then writing to read DB causes indexes to rebuilt and therefore it can block our reads.

My impression is that it conflicts with the idea of reading/write independently. What is the gain from fast saving data to event store, when in the end saving to read database is longer so we aren't really scaling r/w operations independently. Maybe I'm missing something, I'm still learning about these patterns.

PS. English is my second language, I'm sorry for making any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my experience with CQRS, it provides you flexibility in using multiple techniques and technologies that improve performance - according to your requirements.

Example:

- For the Command Part of CQRS, you may use advanced ORM like EF Core,
- While for Query Part, you can use Micro ORM like Dapper (faster) or ADO.NET (even faster).

Another example about how to design the Database:

- You design one database for Command Transactions (Normalized)
- Another synchronized Database for Query (Denormalized) provides better performance on the query side.

You also have many options of how to synchronize between Databases

**So** you are flexible in how to enhance the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is but I will try to lay out my take on it here.

If the databases for read/write are separated completely they will by definition not affect each other. Using CQRS this way means that we **can** scale read/write operations independently.

It may however take some time before an update is propagated to the read model and made available for querying to a client. That is the *cost* that you pay for designing an eventually consistent distributed system.

The synchronization mechanism between the write model and the read model can differ between implementations. However, in a distributed CQRS system the read model is eventually consistent to the write model by design so they are not synchronized at all times. The read model is always catching up and sometimes it will have all information.

I hope that answers your question.